# How to retry a transaction that has failed because of a deadlock?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, deadlock, transactionscope

I use linq-sql and this is what I need.

```
Sub Commit()
Try

StepStart:

Transaction Scope Serialized
Begin Transaction
Check BusinessRule1
Check BusinesRule2

if BusinessRulesFailed
{ Transaction.Rollback }
else {
Query = db.out
db.SubmitChanges()
Transaction.Commit()
}

Catch DeadLockException
Goto StepStart

End Try

End Sub
```

Is it ok to follow this approach? Can someone give me an example in C# or VB.Net

Comment: It might be better if you figured out why you're getting the deadlock, rather than simply retrying the transaction.

Comment: I have a table called assetmeterreadings on which this transaction queries for business rule checking. But that table is constantly used by other transactions.

Comment: @Robert Harvey; you can't... only reduce them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to use this approach. We do something similar. I'd a small delay though, say 500 ms.

With the SQL Server (and Sybase) locking strategy deadlocks will always happen: you can can only reduce the possibility [as per MSDN (for 2000 bit still valid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213042%28SQL.80%29.aspx). Which also says to retry.

I've also seen commercial apps that retry too.

The other option is to enable [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179599%28SQL.90%29.aspx) which is not perfect though

Comment: The problem is that it even happens for simple reads. Can't wrap retry's for all reads. That's not clean.

Comment: Reads should not deadlock usually. Are you sure it not some kind of transaction?

Comment: hmm reads do turn out to be deadlocks, in linq the default transaction isolation level is readcomitted and hence the problem.

Comment: readcomitted is the default all over. it is not the problem: trust me

Comment: please read http://omaralzabir.com/linq_to_sql_solve_transaction_deadlock_and_query_timeout_problem_using_uncommitted_reads/

are you sure that reads should not give out deadlocks?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifiaction btw. I am not wrapping my reads inside transactions anywhere in the app. But the deadlock I got was on a read. A simple read like select p.x=2 and p.y > 10 and p.y <20

Comment: With LINQ I see setting the snapshot isolation as a viable option. Should I use READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ?